# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader error on Pre-Lollipop in android while uploading image with Amazon S3

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, gson

Uploading image to amazon s3 bucket working fine with android 5 and above but getting Gson Error on Pre-Lollipop. Below is the code i am working with.

Error:

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: TransferSerivce-AWSTransferUpdateHandlerThread
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader
    at com.amazonaws.util.json.GsonFactory$GsonReader.<init>(GsonFactory.java:50)
    at com.amazonaws.util.json.GsonFactory.getJsonReader(GsonFactory.java:38)
    at com.amazonaws.util.json.JsonUtils.getJsonReader(JsonUtils.java:101)
    at com.amazonaws.util.json.JsonUtils.jsonToMap(JsonUtils.java:127)
    at com.amazonaws.util.json.JsonUtils.jsonToMap(JsonUtils.java:166)
    at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferRecord.updateFromDB(TransferRecord.java:134)
    at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferDBUtil.getTransferById(TransferDBUtil.java:669)
    at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferService.execCommand(TransferService.java:284)
    at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferService$UpdateHandler.handleMessage(TransferService.java:224)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

This is the code I am using to upload the Image:

```
 ClientConfiguration clientConfig = new ClientConfiguration();
                    clientConfig.setConnectionTimeout(120000); // setting connection time out to be 2 minutes.
                    clientConfig.withConnectionTimeout(120000); // setting connection timeout to be 2 minutes.
                    AmazonS3Client awsClient = new AmazonS3Client(
                            new BasicAWSCredentials("accessKey", "secreatKey"),
                            clientConfig);
                    imagePath = "A" + "/" + compressedFile.getName();
                    TransferUtility transferUtility = new TransferUtility(awsClient, getBaseContext());
                    TransferObserver observer = null;
                    try {
                        observer = transferUtility.upload("bucket-name", imagePath, compressedFile);
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                        Log.e(Tag,""+e.toString());
                    }
```

the above code working fine with lollipop and above but creating issue with pre lollipop

added Gson Dependency too thinking that it might help. But no luck

Gradle Dependencies:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
compile 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.5'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'

compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.2.14'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognito:2.2.14'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.2.14'

compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2' // added gson hoping 
}
```

searched a lot but no clue. Any help deeply appreciated.

Comment: have you tried without the line `compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'` (it is redundant and wrong version)

Comment: yeah aws core includes gson internally initially i didn't had that, it was not working then only i added that one. Now i am using TransferManager it is working fine, The only problem is it is deprecated.

Comment: Have you tried earlier AWS SDK versions? Do you have proguard turned on? I tested the SDK on API level 10 and no issue so far. This is sample I tried https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/blob/master/S3TransferUtilitySample.

Comment: i have also used the same sample and it works fine on android 5 and above. I am building in debug mode so proguard is turned off by default.

Comment: now i am using TransferManager which is deprecated. The idea is to use it in production is it a good idea?

Comment: Does the same sample work on pre Lollipop? I won't recommend TransferManager.

Comment: it is working on lollipop and later. and i saw many issues on AWS forum on android 6 regarding upload and downloads. i think things are not that stable.

Comment: Uh... So the sample app doesn't work on pre Lollipop? Did you test it on emulator or device?

Comment: i have tested on device.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. I tested this sample https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/blob/master/S3TransferUtilitySample. I ran it on emulator API level 10, 18, 19, 23 and on device API level 17. I didn't see the problem you described. Does this sample work for you on pre Lollipop or not? How to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108586/discussion-between-irfan-and-yangfan).

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience with android platform. But the guide [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-http-java-client/setup) might help you to solve the issue. Please note the following warning mentioned in the set up guide.

> For Android, you MUST place the jar files in a directory named "libs" so that the APK packager can find them. Otherwise, you will get a NoClassDefFoundError error at runtime.